# QuickCheck: How to combine two generators?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, frege

I have two generators, `gen_n` & `gen_arr`:

```
gen_n :: Gen Int
gen_n = suchThat arbitrary (\i -> i >= 0 && i <= 10)

gen_elem :: Gen Int
gen_elem = suchThat arbitrary (\i -> i >= 0 && i <= 100)

gen_arr :: Gen [Int]
gen_arr = listOf gen_elem
```

How can I combine these two into a `Gen (Int, [Int])`?

```
combine_two_gens :: Gen a -> Gen b -> Gen (a, b)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**(i)** You can use normal functorial/monadic composition to combine them:

```
gen_comb :: Gen (Int, [Int])
gen_comb = (,) <$> gen_elem <*> gen_arr
```

(`Control.Applicative.liftA2` and `Control.Monad.liftM2` are also fine, of course)

**(ii)** don't use `suchThat` to merely constrain a range. It can be terribly inefficient, as it just generates random instances until the condition is met, discarding the rest. Instead, you could use `elements :: [a] -> Gen a`:

```
gen_elem' :: Gen Int
gen_elem' = elements [0..100]

gen_arr' :: Gen [Int]
gen_arr' = listOf gen_elem'

gen_comb' :: Gen (Int, [Int])
gen_comb' = (,) <$> elements [0..100] <*> listOf (elements [0..100])
```

**Update:** As Zeta remarked below, we can do even better in this case, by using `choose (0,100)` (`choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a`) instead of `elements [0..100]`. See [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.1.0.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#3), or [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.1.0.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html) for the full list of generator combinators.

---

```
*Main> sample gen_arr'
[78]
[2,27]
[12,39]
[92,22,40,6,18,19,25,13,95,99]
...
*Main> sample gen_comb'
(9,[23,3])
(11,[67,38,11,79])
(5,[96,69,68,81,75,14,59,68])
...
```

`suchThat` vs. `elements`:

```
*Main> sample (suchThat arbitrary (\i -> i >= 10000 && i <= 10005))
^CInterrupted.
*Main> sample (elements [10000..10005])
10003
10002
10000
10000
...
```

The `suchThat` generator didn't output anything.

Comment: Consider `choose (0,100)` instead of `elements [0..100]`. While `elements` is great if your range isn't continuous or if your type doesn't have a `Random` instance, `choose` is usually more efficient if your values are in a closed range.